# Is there better way to loop item of array using forEach and make repeat it using setTimout/Interval

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, settimeout

Is there a better way to loop item of an array using forEach and make repeat it using setTimout/Interval or somethin' else?

I need that each item of the array was repeated each value of delay for some time (duration)

Here is link
https://codesandbox.io/s/to-loop-an-element-of-array-dm1eq?file=/src/index.js:140-154

Here is the code but I think it's a difficult solution

```js
const arr = [
  { delay: 1_000, duration: 3_000, msg: "Hello World" }, //repeat msg each sec for 3 sec
  { delay: 2_000, duration: 4_000, msg: "Sup?" } //repeat msg each 2 sec for 4 sec
];

class LoopElem {
  constructor(configs) {
    this.count = 0;
    this.sumDelay = 0;
    this.toLoopElem(configs);
  }

  toLoopElem = (configs) => {
    const that = this;
    const { delay, duration, msg } = configs[that.count];
    setTimeout(function request() {
      that.sumDelay += delay;
      console.log(msg); // each delay shows msg
      if (that.sumDelay >= duration) {
        that.sumDelay = 0;
        that.count += 1;
        // if array have already no item stop repeat it
        if (!configs[that.count]) {
          return null;
        }
        setTimeout(that.toLoopElem, configs[that.count].delay, configs);
        return null;
      }
      setTimeout(request, delay);
    }, delay);
  };
}

new LoopElem(arr);
```

Comment: This question may be more suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) than the Stack Overflow section  Stack Exchange. As they say in their [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), "Code Review is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code.'

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: To answer on Code Review visit this [question over there](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/263000/85177).

Comment: Got it, thank you men